# presentViewController sometimes crash

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I would like to use UIImagePicker, it works fine, but sometimes its causing crash...

```
  UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[imagePicker setDelegate:self];
[[MainViewController sharedInstance] presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:^{
    newPhoto.hidden = NO;
}];
```

and sometimes crash...:

```
-[CALayer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

and it s the same if :

```
UIWindow *rootWin = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

[rootWin.rootViewController presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:^{
}];
```

Comment: Your error says, something released your viewcontroller before you are caling presentViewController:. Try to enable NSZombiesEnabled and you will get where and who deallocating this.

Comment: How can be  after     UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; this line, imagePicker nil? And sometimes its working, sometimes not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've solved my problem. The problem was in another view controller. I don't know why, but my app only crashed when I pressed the image browser button. I found my problem by enable NSZombie, and used instruments with NSZombie. In this way, I found the line in my code, what caused the problem. It was really simple... I released a Label twice... I hope it helps somebody else.